# Using eqref with amspset document class

Tags: cross-referencing, document-classes

I'd like to use `\label{eq:1}` and `eqref{eq:1}`. But it doesn't seem to want to work with the document class I'm using. (The amspset document class can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/mattmastin/teaching/grsc-7700/latex-templates).)

```
\documentclass[reqno, 11pt, letterpaper, cm, unboxed]{amspset}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage[in]{fullpage}
\let\ifpdf\relax
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}
\newcommand{\ml}[1]{\!\begin{multlined}[t]#1\end{multlined}}

\newcommand{\pr}[2]{\begin{solution}{\textbf{#1.}}#2\end{solution}}

\name{Eric Auld}
\class{MATH 2200}
\assignment{Homework 1}
\duedate{April, 10}

\begin{document}

\pr{1}{
 \eq{
  e=mc^2 \label{eq:1}
 }
Suppose we consider \eqref{eq:1}
}

\end{document}
```

When I do this, it does not recognize the reference, and says Latex warning: reference "eq:1" on page 1 undefined on line __.

Anyone have some advice?

Comment: You're using `align*` that doesn't produce numbers, so `\label{eq:1}` will refer to nothing. I can't recommend using commands to enclose environments; use explicitly `solution` and also `equation` or `align` when one is needed. Your document will be *more* legible and structured.

Comment: Thanks! If I'm using align, and only want to label one line, should I put `\notag` after each line I don't want labelled?

Comment: @egreg Can you inform a newbie on the value of having your documents be structured and legible? This is just a homework assignment, and I presume no one will ever look at the code, except for me, and only for about a week. But I am definitely interested in how it could be helpful to have the code be very clear.

Comment: *You* will be looking at the code and in a few months you'll be asking “what the heck is `\pr` doing?”

Answer (score 1):

The `align*` environment you're using with `\eq` doesn't generate a number, so your `\label` command ends up referring to nothing, at least in this particular case. It would refer to a “random” number in the general case, precisely to the last one that has been generated, maybe by a `\section` command.

You get *much* more flexibility, structure and readability if you *don't* hide environments inside commands.

There's no gain in using your input rather than

```
\documentclass[reqno, 11pt, letterpaper, cm, unboxed]{amspset}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage[in]{fullpage}
\let\ifpdf\relax
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%% patch solution to typeset its argument boldface
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\solution}{#1]}{\textbf{#1.}]}{}{}    


\name{Eric Auld}
\class{MATH 2200}
\assignment{Homework 1}
\duedate{April, 10}

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}[1]
\begin{equation}
  e=mc^2 \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
Suppose we consider \eqref{eq:1}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

By the way, it's not recommended using `align` or `align*` as “catch-all” display environments: use them *only* for multiline environments.

In a few month you'll probably be staring at your documents asking yourself “what the `*@$$` is `\pr` doing?” Moreover, code using standard commands is portable from one document to another.

In the same vein, I've patched `solution` so that it typesets its (optional) argument boldface, so that you don't have to use the clumsy

```
\begin{solution}[\textbf{1.}]
```

and your document will comply with the standard. If the Powers That Be (your TA or supervisor, for instance) tell you “what's that boldface doing there?”, you'll just remove the patch and print again the paper, asking in return “What boldface?" `;-)`